# How to import XMPPFramewrok files manually in Cocoa Touch Framework in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift4, xmppframework

I am trying to add XMPPFramework files manually inside my private CocoaTouchFramework which is in Swift 4.

I have added the files manually and also added the dependencies and it's building successfully.

Now I want to use this XMPPFramework files inside my framework. How can i import that?

Edited >>
I found that for importing sub modules I need to create module.modulemap file, which will allow me to user XMPP files inside my framework. Looking forward to hint towards that.

Thanks,

Pratik

Answer (score 0):

First download the sample project and then extract the XMPP framework and place it in your project  [link download project](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git)

Comment: I already did that and its not an issue. I am importing it inside my cocoa touch framework.